# I need help with floating points

Tags: c, floating-point

I am very new to programming, taking my first computer science class. I am writing a program and for some reason whenever I try to calculate the floating point value of any operation it just results in 0.00000. If anyone can please help me I will greatly appreciate it!

```
    #include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
          int numa, numb;
          int sum, halffirst, halfsecond, quotient, remainder;


          // get input
          printf("\nPlease enter two integers: ");
          scanf("%d%d", &numa, &numb);  

          // calculate dimensions
          sum = numa + numb;
          halffirst = (double)numa / 2.0;
          halfsecond = numb / 2;
          quotient = numa / numb;
          remainder = numa % numb;

          // display report
          printf("\n%20s%20s", "Description", "Data");
          printf("\n%20s%20s", "-----------", "----");
          printf("\n%20s%20d", "Sum", sum );
          printf("\n%20s%20lf", "Half (1st #)", halffirst);
          printf("\n%20s%20d", "Half (2nd #)", halfsecond);
          printf("\n%20s%20lf", "Quotient", quotient);
          printf("\n%20s%20d", "Remainder", remainder);

          // format and finish
          printf("\n\n");
          return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because you're using the `int` data type which is an integer. Operations performed on integers tend to produce integers (truncated) so something like:

```
int nom = 6;
int den = 10;
float frac = nom / den;
```

will give you a value of zero since the arithmetic is done on integers and only converted to a float at the end (after the damage is done).

You can get around this by casting, for example:

```
float frac = (float)nom / (float)den;
```

which will make floating point values out of the integers *before* the division.

However, you'd be better off using floating point for all your values up front. The `float` (single precision) or `double` (double precision) is what you're after. Double precision values have more ... well, precision, meaning that they can store more digits and a larger range of numbers as well. For class work, `float` should probably be fine.

Comment: In my code I did (double)numa/2.0. Why does it give me 0.000. Please help me I am so confused and I feel like crying. :(

Comment: @Sarah, even though you coerce the right hand side of `halffirst = (double)numa / 2.0;` into a double, you then try to put it into `halffirst` which is an int so it gets truncated then. "Make it a double", and that's not me ordering a whiskey :-) In fact, make them all doubles, see my final paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

You should assign your variables as float or double to save the correct value instead of using ints.

```
double sum, halffirst, halfsecond, quotient, remainder;
```

Replace the line:

```
int sum, halffirst, halfsecond, quotient, remainder;
```

with the one above.

Comment: Thank you but how do I do this? I am very new sorry... :(

Answer (score 1):

According to C-99 standard section 7.19.6.1 paragraph 9

> If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
>   undefined.251) If any argument is not the correct type for the
>   corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.

`halffirst` and `quotient` is defined as `int` but in the `printf` calls, you are using `%lf` that is the specifier for `double`

```
     printf("\n%20s%20lf", "Half (1st #)", halffirst);
     printf("\n%20s%20lf", "Quotient", quotient);
```

Which is undefined behaviour according to the standard.

Use `%d` to print integers

```
     printf("\n%20s %d", "Half (1st #)", halffirst);
     printf("\n%20s %d", "Quotient", quotient);
```

OR, typecast the integers to `float` before passing

```
     printf("\n%20s%20lf", "Half (1st #)", (float)halffirst);
     printf("\n%20s%20lf", "Quotient", (float)quotient);
```

or typecast the `int` to float before passing it.

Answer (score 0):

All your variables are declared as `int`.

Try using `float` or `double`.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things:

1. If you want to use floating point numbers as variables, then you have to declare your variables as `float` rather than `int`. In C and C++, when you divide a number and assign it to an `int`, the result drops all the decimals, leaving only the real number stored in the variable.
2. If you are diving and you have an integer in your denominator, you have to cast the integer to a float point number, like so:

   `int num1 = 1, num2 = 2;
   float theDiv = num1/(float)num2;`

If you don't do that it will also drop the decimals.

Comment: Thank you for helping however I am still confused. I have halffirst defined as (double)numa/2.0. So why is it giving me 0.000 as an answer?

Comment: Because you are storing the division result in an int. Needs to be a float.

Comment: Oh, looks like you are totally lost. Try this:float halffirst = (double)numa / 2.0;

Answer (score -1):

Types are a nightmare for a beginning programmer.  You're dealing with two types here:
`int`, an integer value, and
`double`, a double-precision floating-point number.

C and similar languages are very pedantic about types, casting, and coercion.  You have to be very careful when dealing with multiple types in a single expression.  Breaking down your line `halffirst = (double)numa / 2.0;` step by step.  Let's use an example; say `numa` has the value 5.

- First, cast `numa` to `double`.  This is fine.  You now have 5.0 as your divisor.
- Divide by 2.0.  The dividend, 5.0, is a double, and the divisor, 2.0, is a double, so the result (naturally) will be a double, 2.5.  Also fine.
- Store the result in `halffirst`.  `halffirst` is an `int` type; we can't directly store the value of a `double` into an `int` variable.  Therefore, we have to convert it; `(int)2.5` yields 2, so we store 2 into `halffirst`.

If you want to store the `double` result of your division, you need to declare the destination variable, `halffirst`, as type `double`, otherwise the implicit conversion at the end will hose you.  `halfsecond` is the same way, for the same reason.  Therefore, in your declarations at the top of the `main` method, try this:

```
int numa, numb;
int sum, quotient, remainder;
double halffirst, halfsecond;
```

Make sense?